# Getting a value cannot be null error with my C# project

Tags: c#

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')'

I am getting this error ^.

I want to make it so after I press CTRL Z on the product code it will stop the loop and proceed to the next lines of code. BUT I put in ctrl z and it goes to the Quantity line and breaks after that. If anyone knows how to fix this error, I think its because the Quantity cant return a Null value since its not setup like product is but I cant find a way around it.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int productCode { get; set; }
    public int productQuantity { get; set; }

    //constructor

    public Transaction(string cName)//, int pCode, int pQuantity
    {
        Name = cName;
    }

    public void AssessProducts()
    {

        int codeInput;
        int qtyInput = 0;
        decimal transTotal = 0;
        double qty201 = 0;
        double qty556 = 0;
        double count201 = 0;
        double count556 = 0;
        double count558 = 0;
        double count909 = 0;
        double count910 = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Product Code: ");
        string ctrlzInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity: ");
        qtyInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (ctrlzInput != null)
        {
            codeInput = int.Parse(ctrlzInput);

            if (codeInput == 201)
            {
                count201 = count201 + 19.99;
            }
            else if (codeInput == 556)
            {
                count556 = count556 + 59.99;
            }
            else if (codeInput == 558)
            {
                count558 = count558 + 20.50;
            }
            else if (codeInput == 909)
            {
                count909 = count909 + 105.99;
            }
            else if (codeInput == 910)
            {
                count910 = count910 + 16.99;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Wrong product code.");
            }

            transTotal = (decimal)((double)transTotal + count201 + count556 + count558 + count909 + count910);
            qty201 = qty201 + qtyInput;
            qty556 = qty556 + qtyInput;


          Console.WriteLine("Product Code: ");
          ctrlzInput = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Quantity: ");
          qtyInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
                
       Console.WriteLine($"Customer Name: {Name} \n\n");
       Console.WriteLine("Items Ordered:\n\n");
       Console.WriteLine("Product #    Product Name              Price            Qty         Line Total\n");
        if (count201 >= 1)
        {
            Console.Write($"Product 210 - ACME Anvil               @ $19.99       *{qty201}      = {qty201 * 19.99} \n");
        }
        if (count556 >= 1)
            Console.Write($"Product 556 - ACME Dynamite            @ $59.99       *{qty556}      = {qty556 * 59.99} \n");
        }
              
    }
```

[image]

[image: Attached the image error as well]

Comment: Please don't post code as image, post as text

Comment: Int.Parse will only work for real integers. Use int.TryParse for a careful check

Comment: please check null or empty values passing.

Answer (score 5):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-5.0):

> **Returns**
>
> String
>
> The next line of characters from the input stream, or `null` if no more lines are available.

And:

> If the **Ctrl+Z** character is pressed when the method is reading input from the console, the method returns `null`. This enables the user to prevent further keyboard input when the `ReadLine` method is called in a loop.